# converting string to list of indices

Tags: python, string, list, file, matrix

I need to find out if a set of paths I have in a text file are valid on an adjacency matrix I have made.

```
myList = []
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList[0] = [False,True,False,False,True]
myList[1] = [True,False,True,True,False]
myList[2] = [False,True,False,True,True]
myList[3] = [False,True,True,False,True]
myList[4] = [True,False,True,True,False]


myFile = open("numbers.txt","r+")

def admatrix(myList, myFile):
    for nextline in myFile:
        nextline = [int(x)-1 for x in list(myFile.strip())]
        for a,b in zip(path, path[1:]):
            if not myList[a][b]:
                return False
            else:
                return True

print admatrix(myFile, myList)
```

This is the current code I have but on this line

```
nextline = [int(x)-1 for x in list(myFile.strip())]
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list'object has no attribute 'strip'
```

How do I fix this, I am a newbie to this so I may be completely wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You switched the parameters

Comment: `print admatrix(myFile, myList)` vs `def admatrix(myList, myFile):`

Comment: Also, changing the value of `nextline` within the loop does nothing, so it's not really clear what you are trying to do. If you want integers instead of booleans, then start your lists with numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just confusing two variables. What I expect you want is:

```
nextline = [int(x)-1 for x in list(nextline.strip())]
```

And at the bottom, where you call the function, it seems like you've swapped argument names. Shouldn't that be `print admatrix(myList, myFile)`